# find match between 2 sql queries

Tags: sql, algorithm, oracle, match

I have two queries from v$sqlarea. For example

query 1: `select * from employee emp where emp.eid = 5`

query 2: `select * from employee v where v.eid = 15`

Both are exactly the same in structure. but they will be compiled separately each time..

I need to match such queries that vary only by alias names or bind variables.

The inbuilt function `utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity()` in oracle provides a pretty good string match algorithm. But sql perspective match is not provided. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

there is a [script on Asktom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1163635055580) that will find exactly this kind of statements (statements **NOT** using binds).

> The output of that last query will show you statements that are identical in the shared 
>   pool after all numbers and character string constants have been removed.  These 
>   statements -- and more importantly their counts -- are the potential bottlenecks.  In 
>   addition to causing the contention, they will be HUGE cpu consumers.

Comment: hi vincent,
the script groups the sqls. i need to present each such query that comes under the group. if there are 20 queries that were grouped by the above script, i need to list down all those 20 queries. how do i do that.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle actually does this internally, to support `cursor_sharing = similar`.  I am not aware that they expose this functionality anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The alias names is a tricky one. You could look for SQLs with the same PLAN_HASH_VALUE as a starting point.